# clear http authentication cache from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-authentication

I am sure this is not a new issue I am facing, but couldn't find any resolution yet.So, we have a ng2 app which uses Windows Authentication. It is implemented using Waffle libraries with Jersey RESTful service. We are implementing logout functionality, which seems to have an issue where browser is caching credentials, until all of it’s instances are closed.

When user launches browser for the first time (first instance of browser), it prompts for credentials as expected. When user clicks on “Logout” option from application, session is invalidated on server. But, next time when user refreshes URL or launches application in new tab, browser do not prompt for credentials.

In Internet Explorer, using document.execCommand(“ClearAuthenticationCache”) clears credentials stored for the user. Is there any equivalent code or way to clear http authentication cache from Chrome?